# Function of a templated class as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I want to create a template class for generic operators. The class will have two structs representing a value as input:

```
struct Value {
   DataType type;
   size_t dataSize;
   char* data;    
};
```

I already have written a type deduction with oldschool switch-cases. After a cast of the data-ptr to the type, I want to apply an operation on the input values like this:

```
template<class Operation>
class ApplyOperation {
    Value* operator()(const Value* a, const Value* b) const {
    //find type of a and b
    //cast a and b to their types
    Operation<aT,bT> op;
    return op(a,b);
  }
};
```

Now I could write for each operation a little struct like this:

```
template<class A, class B>
struct Add {
  A operator()(A a, B b) const { return a + b; }
};
```

I have seen a boost class called operators: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/utility/operators.htm

which I want to use for my purpose. But I don't know how to integrate it since the operators in the structs are no functors. So would it be possible to use it like this?:

```
ApplyOperation<boost::addable::operator+> add;
add(a,b);
```

Actually I'm trying it for testing with this class:

```
template<template<class T, class U, class...> class OperatorClass,class F>
struct ApplyOperator {

    template<class T, class U>
    T foo(T a, U b) {
        OperatorClass<T,U> opClass;
        return opClass.operator+(a,b);  //this works of course
    }
};
```

What I want to get is this:

```
template<template<class T, class U, class...> class OperatorClass,class F>
struct ApplyOperator {

    template<class T, class U>
    T foo(T a, U b) {
        OperatorClass<T,U> opClass;
        return opClass.F(a,b);
    }
};
```

Instantiated like that:

```
ApplyOperation<boost::addable, operator+> add;
```

This doesn't work of course because of the unknown type operator+. So how can I call the operator+-function with templates?

Is there a way to get this solved?

Comment: please post a [mcve] of what you are trying to accompilish

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yihHAMR0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood the question. But it looks like you are trying to provide an object instance (not type) to your template ApplyOperator. Since operator+ is definitely not a type and not an integral constant, it can not be used as a template argument in no way. What you will have to do is to make an operation an argument to the constructor, not the type of the object.

Comment: Is there a way to tell via templates which member function to use?

Comment: No. The only 2 things which can be an argument of a template are type or integral constant. Function pointers are neither.